# 'Save As' image with src from PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm currently displaying images and hiding the src code by having a php file output the image. But when I right click on the image displayed and go down to 'Save As' it prompts me to download the php file not the actual image (obviously because it points to that src).

What can I do to download the actual image instead of displayImage.php?

Comment: Link the image and not a php file?

Comment: You could use `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: Which browser? Doing this in Firefox 8, I end up downloading a file called "images.php.png" (which is a valid png file) when the URL is "images.php?src=public/icons/22/warning.png" (actual source is in the src param, all correct mimetype headers are set in the PHP file). +1 I've never seen this before, wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't prompt you to download the PHP file, it simply uses that as the file name, because that is the file name from which it got the image data. If you manually input a valid image file name and try to open what you saved, it should still be a valid image.

You may also be able to give it a sensible name by including the file name in a `Content-Disposition:` header from your PHP file, e.g.

```
 $filename = 'image.jpg';
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
 // Don't forget the Content-Type as well...
 // Output image here
```

...however this relies on the browser handling this sensibly, which not all of them do :-(

Comment: I'd recommend including a content-type header as well.  And a content-length header (not strictly necessary but the browser can't show download progress without it)

Comment: @GordonM Just realised that point should be made at the same time as your comment and edited the answer :-) - although the `download progress` is irrelevant, because you are doing `right click -> save as...` so the image has already been downloaded, you're actually just moving it locally from the browser temp/cache directory to wherever you save it.

Comment: thanks, yup already have the content-type but added the Content-Disposition header and seems to work

Answer (score 3):

You can send a filename in the header.

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="some.png"');
```

Comment: `attachment` risks forcing a download box, you should use `inline` instead - although the general concept is sound - +1

Answer (score 1):

1. Send the correct content type in the image generator script:

   header('Content-type: image/jpg');
2. If you want to have the .jpg extension when a PHP script is outputting an image, you'll need to do a htaccess or httpd.conf rewrite, where you can rewrite a .jpg request, to your php image generator script.

See mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html